# Search for all words from a list for all files in directory, and return context

Tags: python, list

I have a list of Keywords

```
Animals = ['dogs' , 'cat' , 'bird' ....]
```

And I have a directory with many files which may have  occurrences of the 1 or multiple of the keywords.

File1.txt

- "I'm a car I go beep"
- "I'm a cat, I go meow"
- "I'm a dog, I go woof"

File2.txt

- "I'm a bell I go ding"
- "I'm a bird, I go tweet"
- "I'm a printer, I go brrr"

I want to search every file in the directory, and check for all occurrences from my Animal list.
I want to record the fileName , line Number, the match, line.

example desired output:

- File1.txt , 2 , cat , "I'm a cat, I go meow"
- File1.txt , 3 , dog, "I'm a dog, I go woof"
- File2.txt , 2 , bird, "I'm a bird, I go tweet"

Is this possible? is Python the right tool?
I have been able to run some regex tests with python but I'm having trouble accessing the specific
Line Number, Match, and line.

```
import os
import re

words = ['dog' , 'cat' , 'bird' ]

rx = re.compile('|'.join(words), re.I)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\MySearchDirectory\\'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            with open(root + filename) as df:
                data = df.read()
                for match in rx.finditer(data):
                    print(filename + ' , ' + str(match) + ' , ' + str(match.span()))
```

Comment: not sure what the best way to do this is as I dislike regex, but you should definitely use `glob` over `os` to get the filenames as it'll be a lot shorter.


`list_of_text_files = glob.glob('C:\\MySearchDirectory\\*.txt')`

Comment: `glob` is also built in so you should have it

Comment: hi thank you for your comment, I will try to re-do the code with glob, I saw some stuff about that while searching for this. If i don't use regex, i fear i would just be brute forcing the search. so for every element from my wordSearch list, i would have check every line in every file.

Comment: The regex is still checking every line in every file; there's no way to escape that (other than using a database instead of a flat file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use a regex when Python's standard `in` operator will do the job, IMO:

```
import os

words = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']

for root, _, files in os.walk(r'C:\MySearchDirectory'):
    for path in filter(lambda p: p.endswith('.txt'), files):
        with open(os.path.join(root, path)) as f:
            for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                for word in filter(lambda w: w in line, words):
                    print(f'{path}, {i+1}, {word}, {line.strip()}')
```

Using `filter` vs a list comprehension vs an `if` within the loop is a matter of taste, but in this case I think it's the most straightforward option since it makes the two filtering conditions (files need to end in `.txt`, words need to be present in the line) easy to discern at a glance.

Output:

```
File1.txt, 2, cat, "I'm a cat, I go meow"
File1.txt, 3, dog, "I'm a dog, I go woof"
File2.txt, 2, bird, "I'm a bird, I go tweet"
```

Comment: wow samwise, thank you. WOW, this is really amazing. it's going to take me some time to understand  all the pieces but this is exactly what I was looking for. This is frighteningly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

```
from pathlib import Path

def find_occurrences(file, any_word:list) -> list:
    occurrences = []
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
        lines = text.split('\n')
        for line_number, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
            matched_words = [word for word in any_word if word in line]
            if matched_words:
                occurrence = {
                    "file": file, 
                    "line_number": line_number, 
                    "line": line, 
                    "matched_words": matched_words
                }
                occurrences.append(occurrence)
    return occurrences

occurrences = []
for file in Path(r"C:\\MySearchDirectory\\").glob("**/*.txt"):
    occurrences += find_occurrences(file, any_word=["cat", "dog"])
occurrences
```

First we loop all the ".txt" files in the directory and execute the function `find_occurrences` for each file. This function returns list of occurrences and we update our final results with that. The function itself just reads one file, iterates through each line of the file, checks each line if they contain the specified words and stores to results if they do.

The returned list of dictionary is structured as:

```
[
    {
        'file': 'C:\\MySearchDirectory\\subdir\\file1.txt', 
        'line_number': 5, 
        'matched_words': ['cat', 'dog'], 
        'line': 'meau cat, hau hau dog'
    }, 
    ...
]
```

If you need additional things, just adjust the occurrence dictionary. Note that line_number starts from one. This seemed to be the intended from the example.